# Excel RANGE VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

```
STUDENT TIME    SCORE   WANT
JOHN    1   68  146
JOHN    2   78  146
JOHN    3   77  146
JOHN    4   91  146
JOHN    5   96  146
JAMES   1   66  119
JAMES   2   53  119
JAMES   3   80  119
JAMES   4   96  119
JAMES   5   50  119
JAMES   6   94  119
```

I have data COLUMNS 'STUDENT' AND 'TIME' AND 'SCORE' and wish to create 'WANT' and the rule which for I will need VLOOKUP is this: WANT = the sum of the SCORE values at TIMES 1 and 2, so I WISH TO USE VLOOKUP to find the 'SCORE' values for each 'STUDENT' at TIMES 1 and 2 and take the sum.

Comment: VLOOKUP is not the correct formula for this.  Use SUMIFS()

Comment: @ScottCraner I think it is because I wish to calculate this sum and then fill it into another column that features just 'STUDENT' and 'TIME'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataset is ordered by "student name" (with unique student names), then "time", you could use :

Classical way, in F2 :

```
=IF(AND(B2=1,B3=2,A2=A3),C2+C3,IF(AND(B2=2,B1=1,A2=A1),C2+C1,OFFSET($F$1,MATCH(A2,A$2:A2,0),0)))
```

Greedy way (Office365 needed), in E2 :

```
=SUM(FILTER($A$2:$C$12;($B$2:$B$12<=2)*($A$2:$A$12=A2)))-3
```

Reference :
[image: Time]

Answer (score 1):

You can try `SUMIFS()` in this way.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$12,$B$2:$B$12,{1,2},$A$2:$A$12,A2))
```

It may need to array entry for older versions of excel. Array entry  by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

[image]